# Expected value of $\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq m}X_i-\min\limits_{1\leq i\leq m} X_i$ for balls and bins problem

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request, poisson-distribution, balls-in-bins

Recently I came across the following problem which has occupied me for a few weeks. This is just out of curiosity, and also I can't find any research paper on this particular question .

> **Problem :** Given $N$ balls, each ball is placed in a box chosen uniformally at random among  $m $  numbered boxes, Let $X_i $ denote the random variable counting the number of balls in box $i$. Define $Y=\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq m}X_i-\min\limits_{1\leq i\leq m} X_i$.
>   What is the expected value and the variance of the variable $Y$?

I am looking for any reference or research paper providing an answer (approximations) to the problem when $\mathbf{N}$ **is large** and $m$ is constant.

Comment: Should that not be $\text{max} X_i - \text{min} X_i$ ? - why do you need the $j$ index? And why would your numbered boxes run from 0? Presumably, they run from1 to $m$.

Comment: Yes , you're right. I can use the same index without any problem. Starting from $0$ instead of $1$ is definitely an error. I am going to correct it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a satifactory answer, but here is a small observation: If $M_m := \mathbb{E}\left[\max_{1\leq i\leq m} W_i \right]$ denotes the expectation of the maximum of $m$ i.i.d. standard normal variables $W_1, \cdots, W_m$, then we have

> $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\mathbb{E}\left[ \max_{1\leq i \leq m} X_i - \min_{1\leq i \leq m} X_i \right]
> = \frac{2M_m}{\sqrt{m}} . \tag{*}$$

The idea is as follows. Roughly speaking, the main source of the correlation between $X_i$'s is the condition that the total sum $X_1 + \cdots + X_m$ is fixed. That is, we can loosely think of each $X_i$ as the following re-centered version

$$ X_i \quad {``}\approx{\text{''}} \quad \tilde{X}_i + \frac{N}{m} - \frac{\sum_{k=1}^m\tilde{X}_k}{m} $$

of some i.i.d. random variables $\tilde{X}_1, \cdots, \tilde{X}_m$. Since this re-centering does not affect the difference, we expect that $Y \approx \tilde{Y} := \max_i \tilde{X}_i - \min_i \tilde{X}_i$. Taking advantage of the independence, it is easier to investigate $\tilde{Y}$ instead.

---

Here is a more detailed argument. If we consider

$$ \tilde{Z}_i = \frac{X_i - (N/m)}{\sqrt{N/m}} $$

then the random vector $\tilde{Z} = (\tilde{Z}_1, \cdots, \tilde{Z}_m)$ converges in distribution to the multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, C)$ with the covariance matrix $C$ satisfying

$$ C_{ij} = \delta_{ij} - \frac{1}{m}.$$

So we consider a multivariate normal vector $Z = (Z_1, \cdots, Z_m) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, C)$. We also introduce a normal variable $\bar{Z} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{1}{m})$ which is independent of $Z$. Finally, consider $W_i = Z_ i + \bar{Z}$. Then we easily compute that

$$ \operatorname{Cov}(W_i, W_j) = C_{ij} + \frac{1}{m} = \delta_{ij}, $$

from which we find that $(W_i)$ is an i.i.d. standard normal variables. Since $Z_i - Z_j = W_i - W_j$, we may study the maximum and minimum of $W$ instead. So

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\max_i Z_i - \min_i Z_i\right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[\max_i W_i - \min_i W_i\right]
= 2\mathbb{E}\left[\max_i W_i\right]
= 2M_m
\end{align*}

Using this we can prove that $\text{(*)}$ holds.

Comment: I think that, this is a good approximation of order $o (\sqrt N)$ (given that $M_m$ is a known constant). I would read your answer in details later.

Comment: This is what I am looking for , using the notation from the question then $$ \mathbb{E}\left[ Y\right] =\sqrt{N} \frac{2M_m}{\sqrt{m}} +o (\sqrt{N})$$ This is a first order approximation, the next step would be te obtain à better approximation . Can we obtain a similar result for the variance?

Comment: @Elaqqad, The main source of error is the normal approximation (classical CLT to be precise). Thinking that $X$ is the sum of i.i.d. variables, I guess that some nice estimation may be possibly available. And for variance, again the computation boils down to computing $\operatorname{Var}(\max_i W_i - \min W_i)$. But unlike that we have estimates $M_m \sim \sqrt{2\log m}$, I am not entirely sure how its variance will behave asymptotically in $m$. Mind you, we also have $(\max_{1\leq i \leq m} W_i)/M_m \to 1 $ as $m \to \infty$, so we expect concentration near $M_m$.

Comment: thank you for the details. It seems that this is the best I can get.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen:

- Greenwood and Glasgow (1950), Distribution of Maximum and Minimum Frequencies in a Sample Drawn from a Multinomial distribution, *The Annals of Mathematical Statistics*, 21(3), p.416-424  https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177729800
- Freeman, P. R.   (1979), Algorithm AS 145: Exact Distribution of the Largest Multinomial Frequency, *Applied Statistics*, 28(3), p.333-6
  http://www.jstor.org/stable/2347220?
- Carrado , C (2011), The exact distribution of the maximum, minimum and the range of Multinomial/Dirichlet and Multivariate Hypergeometric frequencies, *Statistics and Computing* 21(3), 349-359  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11222-010-9174-3

Comment: I have seen the first article , it is about only some particular cases ( the multinomial distribution is very abstract and contains more information then needed which makes it hard to have a good estimation depending only on $N $ and $m $ ). I Will see the other references.  Thanks

Comment: For the second article, it describes only an algorithm for the $ \text{max}(X_i)$ and it did not give any formula for it. The problem of estimating the maximum of $n$ uniform binomial variables is well-studied in other papers and known as the max-load, its expected value is : $$N/m+\sqrt{N\frac{\text{log}(m)}{m}}$$ but I don't know how to generalize the methods to answer my question. It is also important to note that $ \text{max}(X_i)$ and $ \text{min}(X_i)$ are note independent

Comment: the third article does not answer my question either. Thanks for the references anyway